# How to reset a value in ajax search to paginate results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having problems with a "load more button". I try to show the second page of results (and the others ahead) every time I make a new search, but the value I use to determine which is the current page of results, is always increasing... And I need to reset it when user makes a new search

here's the code I'm using

html:

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="search"> Search </button>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

js to send form:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').on('click', function(){
    var page_search = 1; 
    var search= $('#input').val();
    showSearch(page_search);
   });

          $("#load-more").click(function () {
            page_search++; 
            showSearch(page_search); 
          }); 

          function showSearch(page_search){
            $.post( 'search.php', {'page_search': page_search, 'search': search}, function(data){
              if(data.trim().length == 0){
                $("#result").show().html("no more results found");
              }else if(page_search=1){
              $("#result").html(data); 
              }else{
              $("#result").append(data); 
              }
            });
          }
    </script>
```

php file: is reciving the input text value and the current page to generate a limit to show the results, something like:

```
$item_per_page = 5;
$position = (($page-1) * $item_per_page);
$search= $_POST['search'];
$page=$_POST["page_search"];

$query=("SELECT columns from table oder by blabla DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
```

The problem is with page_search++ and how can I reset that variable each time I make a new search, otherwise is just increasing and increasing and never start how it should be, just at the first search but then is useless

Comment: Your trackrecord seems to be a bit egotistical, so why should we help you? Learn how we roll, upvote and mark as answer if it was useful to you as it will help us to build up a profile. Deleting and recreating the question will not "resolve" this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP counter instead of a JavaScript counter. Copy-paste next two codes in two files with the given names, the open "ajax1.php" in your browser to see it running :

**ajax1.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
function my_button ()
{ $.ajax( { url     : "ajax2.php",
            success : function ( data )
            { document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data; }, // ◄■■ GET DATA
            error   : function ( xhr )
            { alert( "error" ); }
        } );
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="my_button()">
    <button onclick="my_button()">Load more</button> <!-- ◄■■ LOAD BUTTON -->
    <div id="result"> <!-- ◄■■ DIV TO DISPLAY DATA -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ajax2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION["page_search"] ) ) // ◄■■  FOR THE FIRST PAGE.
   $_SESSION["page_search"] = 0; // ◄■■ CREATE COUNTER.
$database = array( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                  21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37 );
echo implode( ",",array_slice( $database,$_SESSION["page_search"],5 ) );
$_SESSION["page_search"] += 5; // ◄■■  INCREASE COUNTER.
if ( $_SESSION["page_search"] > count( $database ) ) // ◄■■ FOR THE LAST PAGE.
   unset( $_SESSION["page_search"] ); // ◄■■ DESTROY COUNTER.
?>
```

I use an array to represent the database data, and `array_slice` to represent your `select ... limit ...`.

Everytime the counter reaches the end it re-starts.

Comment: Expecting an up vote and a mark for this? Well, you got one from me, but don't expect the mark. Btw, I like this `◄■■`

Comment: How about using [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) `range(1,37);` instead of filling the array manually.

Comment: @dbf, first time I hear about `range` (I will use it from now on!).

Comment: hello guys! thanks for helping me, actually yes! I could use php instead but I really need to do this based on a javascript or jquery solution, I mean in first 'onclick' event (search), the variable is sent like '1' which means the php file will sent back first page of results, and for the second 'onclick' event (load more) the variable is sent like '2,3,4,5,6,7...etc' to show as many pages of results as they are... and finally if I make a new search (first event again) this variable reset its value to the first one, to be usefull again for showing more results when second event is used again

Comment: @kukiko11, you have to reset the counter when there are no more results from you sql query, but it happens on server side, so you have to do it with PHP, that's why you need a PHP counter, not a JavaScript counter.